# What is the spectral domain?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, spectral-analysis

From https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08097.pdf, "Geometric deep learning: going beyond Euclidean data". Here are some uses:

1. "methods of signal processing on graphs, which have
   previously been reviewed in this Magazine [43], can be applied
   to this setting, in particular, in order to define an operation
   similar to convolution in the **spectral domain**"
2. "The first formulation of CNNs on graphs is due to
   Bruna et al. [52], who used the definition of convolutions in
   the **spectral domain**."
3. The key difference between these approaches is in the way a
   convolution-like operation is formulated on graphs and manifolds.
   One way is to resort to the analogy of the Convolution
   Theorem, defining the convolution in the **spectral domain**.

What is the spectral domain, and what does it mean in these contexts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have time series data such as $x_t$, it is the representation of the data in time domain $t$. You can apply Fourier transform, and bring this series into the frequency space:
$$s_w=F(x_t)\equiv\int e^{iwt}x_tdt$$
The new series $s_w$ is called a spectrum, hence, this is the representation of the same data in the spectral domain.

Convolution is an operator such as:
$$(x*y)_t=\int x_{t+h} y_hdh$$
You can easily show that 
$$F((x*y)_t)=s_w F(y_t)$$
In other words instead of an expensive operation of convolution in time space (two nested loops), you get a simple multiplication in spectral space (a single loop)

Comment: Looks like you're right! "This property allows to express the convolution of two functions in the spectral domain as the element-wise product of their Fourier transforms".

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Laplacian matrix of a graph and "spectral" in the eigenvalue sense?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson Not directly, but be aware that the discrete Fourier transform has a kind of "linear algebra" interpreration:  we are expressing a discretized function (signal) as a linear combination of an orthonormal basis of other discretized signals $ce^{iwt}$.